# Was it just George that Jodie didn't like?

Tags: movie, horror, amityville

In the 2005 film version of *The Amityville Horror*, there is the following dialogue.:

> It's okay, Mommy. Jodie won't hurt you. She thinks you're a good mommy. But the man who lives here...she says he's bad. She wants him to go away. He makes her do bad things.

So if George moved out, Kathy with her children could've stayed in the house and live with no problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jodie has been killed by her brother possessed by the evil spirit in the house.
So it seems logical that what she don't like in George is that evil spirit slowly taking possession of him.
If he were to leave the house, its difficult to know what would have happened :

- does this spirit can take possession of a woman (the mother) or a little boy ? in that case it will restart again
- does this spirit need some grown up man with a bit of aggressive personnality to begin the slow process of possession?
  in that case they will be peaceful until one of the boy is old enough to be possessed

In my opinion, you need some kind of specific personnality for the spirit of the Reverend Jeremiah Ketcham to begin to mess with you...
Ronald Defeo was the only one possessed, not his father or his little brothers, so it must need something to begin with